# How can I hide Youtube controls but show the Fullscreen button?

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, embed

I am trying to hide the controls, but show the youtube fullscreen button, so that the player looks like the vimeo player.

I have added the following parameters after my embed URL:`?&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&fs=1`

However, it only hides all of the controls.  Is it possible to only show full screen button?

Note: the `<iframe allowfullscreen>` has this option set.

Answer (score 4):

As of September 2018, this doesn't seem to be possible directly with the YouTube iFrame Player API. You can hide all controls (controls=0), or you can hide the fullscreen button specifically (fs=0), but you cannot exclusively display the fullscreen button by itself (i.e., controls=0&fs=1 won't work.)

However, conceivably you can hide all controls and overlay your own custom fullscreen button, and use the browser Fullscreen API to invoke fullscreen on the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Jacob
You can use parameter 'fs' to implement what you want.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Sample:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?fs=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: To be clear, OP is asking how to hide controls AND keep the fullscreen button intact. controls=0 hides ALL controls, including the fullscreen button. fs=1 doesn't seem to override controls=0.

Comment: The `fs`is in the wrong place here. It should be a param on the end of the URL e.g. `?fs=0` rather than a param on the iFrame element.